# QML: Any way of using the standard integer RGB values?

Tags: qt, colors, qml, rgb, rgba

I'm using **Qt 5.7** on **Windows 10** and I'm relatively new to **QML**. I am currently adding some colors to my application and it struck me that there seems to be no way of using the plain integer RGB values (not hexadecimals) for colors. There are (as far as I know) three direct ways (without using the Qt C++ functions of `QColor` in combination with the `QML` code) of setting an item to a specific color:

- `Qt.rgba(...)` - there are two problems I'm having with this the first one being the usage of floating point numbers for the `RGB` values and the second one being the weird call - I find myself forgetting quite often that I have to put `Qt.` in front of the function and needless to say this is annoying (but this is just me :P):

  ```
  Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: Qt.rgba(0.502, 0.502, 0.502, 1)
    border.width: 1
  }
  ```
- `#` - again I have two problems here the first one being that obvious inconsistency if we compare it to the `Qt.rgba(...)` function in terms of placement of the `alpha` value (here in front and not at the end like the last argument of the `Qt.rgba(...)`) and the second one being the usage of hexadecimals:

  ```
  Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "#FF808080"
    border.width: 1
  }
  ```
- color names - this is nice (perhaps) if English is your native language and you are familiar with the vast amount of color names available in Qt (which uses the [SVG color naming](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords)):

  ```
  Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "grey"
    border.width: 1
  }
  ```

All three coloring conventions above represent the same color (`RGB`: 128, 128, 128). I really prefer using the normal integer values since I'm more familiar with those. Is it possible to use those without any extra effort in QML?

Comment: Don't know if it works, but   `color: Qt.rgba(128/255., 128/255., 128/255., 1)` could worth the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Building off what @Gwen said, you can define your own function that takes integers and does the conversion to floats, and then call that everywhere.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is not included as a standard feature?

Comment: I have no idea. You'd have to ask on the mailing lists in the hope of a Qt developer who's been around for a while seeing it.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I use QML already 4 years, didn't even think about the usage of integers like colors in UI

Comment: Good for you, I started with QML like 3 weeks ago or so. And before that I was using a lot of integer RGB values (not in the context of UI development). Still the fact that `QColor`  provides such a feature does mean that there are people out there who actually find it useful.

Comment: You could file a suggestion in Jira, but I think this is one of those things that you'll get use to eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting ints to floats, we can convert from ints to hexadecimal:

```js
    function rgb(r, g, b, a) {
        return "#"
             + (a ? a.toString(16).padStart(2, "0") : "")
             + r.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
             + g.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
             + b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
    }
```

Here's a demonstration with Red, Green, Blue sliders:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    property var col: rgb(redSlider.value, greenSlider.value, blueSlider.value)

    ColumnLayout {
        Frame {
            Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 200
                implicitHeight: 200
                color: col
                Frame {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    background: Rectangle { }
                    Text {
                        text: col
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        SliderText {
            id: redSlider
            value: 176
        }

        SliderText {
            id: greenSlider
            value: 196
        }

        SliderText {
            id: blueSlider
            value: 222
        }
    }

    function rgb(r, g, b, a) {
        return "#"
             + (a ? a.toString(16).padStart(2, "0") : "")
             + r.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
             + g.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
             + b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
    }
}

//SliderText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
RowLayout {
    property alias value: slider.value
    Slider {
        id: slider
        from: 0
        to: 255
        stepSize: 1
    }
    Text {
        text: slider.value
    }
    Text {
        text: slider.value.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)